# display none "Who to follow" twitter

Tags: css, twitter

I am trying to hide the "Who to follow" box in my twitter account.

For this purpose I use a Chrome extension called Minimalist.

For some reason my CSS code is not working:

```
//not working
.wtf-module{
display: none;
}

//not working
.js-wtf-module{
display: none;
}

//not working
.dashboard:nth-child(2){
display: none;
}
```

Any idea?

All suggestions are more than welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me in Firefox 27. I'm not able to test in Chrome right now.

```
.wtf-module, .js-wtf-module {
    display: none !important;

}
```

You might also be inspired by this configuration from http://nakkaya.com/2014/01/26/pentadactyl-configuration/:

```
@-moz-document domain("twitter.com") {
    div.module.trends{ display: none !important; }
    div.module.site-footer{ display: none !important; }
    div.module.wtf-module.js-wtf-module.has-content{ display: none !important; }
    div.global-nav{ display: none !important; }
    .wrapper.white { background: none !important;}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`.wtf-module.has-content {display: none;}`

Comment: ...very appropriate name for the module "what the f*k module" ;)